# Use the prop pass a object, but did not get the value

Tags: vue.js

I have a `child` component, it accept a `todo` object.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
      props: ['todo'],
      template: '<span>{{ todo.text }}</span>'
    })
    
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#box',
      data: {
        todo: {
          text: 'Study English',
          isComplete: false
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
  <child v-bind="todo"></child>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the `todo.text` is `Study English`, but it do not shows up. Why it do not show the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow that you have does not bind anything since you are not passing the prop name `todo` over to the child.

```
<child v-bind="todo"></child>
```

should be

```
<child v-bind:todo="todo"></child>
```

Alternatively, you can use the shorthand method like the one below

```
<child :todo="todo"></child>
```

By passing through the `todo` Object, you can now use `{{ todo.text }}` as you did in the child component.

[This](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic) doc should help.

Answer (score 0):

You bind a object to the component:

```
 <child v-bind="todo"></child>
```

and the object `todo` data is this:

```
todo: {
    text: 'Study English',
    isComplete: false
}
```

it is equals to:

```
 <child v-bind:text='Study English' v-bind:isComplete=false ></child>
```

In your component, the `prop` should like this:

```
props: ['text', 'isComplete']
```

---

Otherwise you can pass the `todo` like this: `v-bind:todo="todo"`.